# How to show the names of the sets on a Venn diagram plot made with venn?

Tags: python, venn

I have installed the python package **venn** to plot venn diagrams.

```
Name: venn
Version: 0.1.3
Summary: Venn diagrams for 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 sets
Home-page: https://pypi.org/project/venn/
Author: Kirill Grigorev
License: GPLv3
```

I would like to know if there is a way to show set labels next to the set. Not only a legend, but also the **set names**.

```
from venn import venn
%matplotlib inline

musicians = {
    "Members of The Beatles": {"Paul McCartney", "John Lennon", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"},
    "Guitarists": {"John Lennon", "George Harrison", "Jimi Hendrix", "Eric Clapton", "Carlos Santana"},
    "Played at Woodstock": {"Jimi Hendrix", "Carlos Santana", "Keith Moon"}
}
venn(musicians)
```